# pom.xml without dependencies using maven-publish plugin in a multi module gradle project

Tags: gradle, multi-module, maven-publish

I've a gradle project with subprojects. Every subproject produces a jar and a pom that it's published on a repository

1) In the main project gradle file there's a subprojects section that I used to define what and where to publish:

*snippet from rootproject.gradle:*

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    publishing {

        publications {
            mavenJava(org.gradle.api.publish.maven.MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
            }
        }

        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'file://c:/temp/repo'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) In the gradle file of one of my subprojects, I've added some dependencies:

*snippet from subproject.gradle:*

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'my-group', name: 'my-module', version:'1.1.0'
}
```

If I run "**gradle publish**" from the rootproject it will correctly publish every subproject. However, I noticed that **the dependency defined in the subproject is missing from the pom publication** related to the subproject.

If I cut and paste the content of the subprojects section in each subproject, the generated pom file contains the correct dependency. 
It seems that “**from components.java**” is not a reference to something that should be used by the publish task to produce the pom, but the task will publish exactly what components.java contains when you call the “from” method.

**As a workaround**, I moved the subprojects code in a method defined in the root:

*rootproject.gradle*

```
def configurePublishing(project) {
    project.apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    …
}
```

And I called it from each subproject:

*subproject.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'my-group', name: 'my-module', version:'1.1.0'
}

configurePublishing(project)
```

**Another solution** could be adding a switch in the subprojects section and **centralize everything** in the gradle file of the root project:

```
subprojects { subProject ->
    switch(subproject.name) {
        case: ‘my-subproject-with-dependencies’ {
            dependencies {
                compile group: 'my-group', name: 'my-module', version:'1.1.0'
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
}
```

Is it an acceptable approach? Is there a best practice to follow? Is there an easier way to do it?